# Interpretation of McNemar test example

Tags: r, categorical-data, mcnemar-test

In this tutorial

https://learningstatisticswithr.com/book/chisquare.html

in **Example 12.8.1** I understand the result of the test

```
## McNemar's chi-squared = 12.033, df = 1, p-value = 0.0005226
```

But they conclude:

> And in fact, it looks like the ads had a negative effect: people were
> less likely to vote AGPP after seeing the ads

Why do they conclude that? How can we know if the effect of the ads (in this case) is positive or negative?

Comment: What are the counts of `response_before` for `yes` and `response_after` for `no` and `yes`?

Comment: response_before_yes_response_after_yes=5; response_before_yes_response_after_no=25; response_berfore_no_response_after_yes=5;  response_before_no_response_after_no=65; therefore after the ads the response is 5 in both cases, there is no negative effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data should be something like this:

```
tab = as.table(rbind(c(65,5),c(25,5)))

colnames(tab) = c("no","yes")
rownames(tab) = c("no","yes")

names(dimnames(tab)) <- c("before", "after")
    
tab
      after
before no yes
   no  65   5
   yes 25   5
```

And the test goes:

```
mcnemar.test(tab)

    McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction

data:  tab
McNemar's chi-squared = 12.033, df = 1, p-value = 0.0005226
```

You can interpret it as, before seeing the ad, 30% responded yes:

```
 rowSums(tab)
 no yes 
 70  30
```

After seeing the ad, only 10% responded yes:

```
colSums(tab)
 no yes 
 90  10
```

Hence it has a negative effect.